# Make voting arrows look different after voting

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, android-app

There's no change to the appearance of the up/down voting arrows on answers with the Android app at the moment. This means that whe you return to a question there's no way of seeing which answers you've already upvoted (or not)

For example, I have voted on one of these answers, can anyone tell me which one, or if it was up or down?

[image]

(This is on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus running stock Android 4.3 in case this is something theme related, and I did pick up the latest Stack app update about an hour ago - this is present in both the latest version, and the one before it)

## Update:

Have done some more testing on this, and it seems that vote indicators do change colour properly on questions (they change to a reddish-pink background) but not on answers.

When I vote on an answer using the app the background circle briefly flashes red/pink and then goes back to the normal unhighlighted background colour after a fraction of a second, this seems to suggest that this is a bug rather than deliberate behaviour. Have confirmed this on SuperUser and Android.se.

Comment: V 0.1.5 on the Galaxy Shows the difference by changing the arrow to red in color for the votes I did from the web site.

Comment: Does it vary by which SE site you're on? (Not an app user so perhaps a silly question, but on the various SE sites there are different graphics for the voting buttons, so perhaps there are some that don't have the changed ones implemented?)

Comment: Question updated I can see this on both SE 2.0 sites and the original trilogy, but it does only seem to be happening on Answer votes, Question votes change colour as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in a previous update:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just to support [GAThrawn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/133427/gathrawn)'s question and the comments raised, the behavior seems the same on:

- Android.SE
- StackOverflow
- StackOverflow Meta
- Cooking.SE

The screenshots are all questions / answers I have upvoted. This is on a Samsung Galaxy S4, using deodexed stock ROM (Android 4.2.2).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @geff and after I used you in my screenshot too!