# Vote action isn't shown until the question is reloaded

Tags: bug, android-app

I've recently noticed that on the Stack Exchange Android application, if I cast a vote on a post the vote action (red arrow) is only shown for around half a second and then the vote appears to be retracted (similar to when a vote is immediately reversed when the reputation requirement isn't met).

Let's use [this post as an example](https://superuser.com/questions/954324/can-i-send-audio-between-pcs-using-cable):

[image]

Have not yet cast a vote on it; let's cast an upvote:

[image]

half a second later, this gets 'reversed' but however *still* shows the upvote I cast, but doesn't show that *my user* has voted yet:

[image]

if I try to re-cast the same vote, the upvote count increases to 5 before it is reversed, with the 'You have already voted' error:

[image]

then if I refresh the question (by pulling down on the question), it now shows my user voted.

This is on the Stack Exchange Beta Android app (1.0.72) on a Huawei Ascend P8 Lite.
I also temporarily left the Beta program, and can confirm this bug exists on the full public (non-beta) version of the app also.
This question has a *very* similar issue to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263334/the-app-forgets-that-i-voted-when-i-scroll-the-question), but however this bug exists *without* any further input (such as scrolling).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not exactly; this bug occurs with no scrolling whatsoever. I personally think there's enough distinction between the two.

Comment: @cybermonkey The root problem is the same in the two questions. I don't think scrolling has any effect on the issue at all, but if you feel it does, add this or any other relevant info to the other question, either briefly in a comment, or an answer if you have a more substantial report to make.  This allows us to have *one* bug report and not 2 bug reports for the same issue. Which saves staff time from reading and collating data, which  will essentially help get bugs fixed more quickly, which is what you want ;)