# Material Design in Stack Exchange App

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I wonder, if Google's Material Design is applied on Stack Exchange app, it would be great. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes it would. But it's not serious enough to be implemented at the first place. The dev team have a long TODO list to go.

Answer (score 6):

While I agree that apps look much better when they're designed to meet the design guidelines for the host operating system (e.g. Material Design on Android), there are lots of bugs and feature requests which are ***much*** more important than changing the design:

- [Allow us to vote to delete from the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app)
- [Add chat rooms for Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191334/add-chat-rooms-for-android-app)
- [Add review queues to Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215841/add-review-queues-to-android-app)
- [The app forgets that I voted when I scroll the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263334/the-app-forgets-that-i-voted-when-i-scroll-the-question)

...and [many more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app).

I think that it is important that bugs which harm the usability of an application and highly requested features are implemented before the design is updated, when the current design is working quite nicely.